# how to style createMaterialTopTabNavigator (sitting too high)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to style my material top tabs using createMaterialTopTabNavigator from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs'. Currently, they look like this:[image]

With this code:

```
//Home top tabs
function HomeTopTabs() {
  return (
      <TopTab.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeFeed">
        <TopTab.Screen name="HomeFeed" component={Home} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="FriendFeed" component={FriendsScreen} />
      </TopTab.Navigator>
    
  );
}
```

*Both screens render a different list of items fetched from the db. This method renders the lists correctly, but as you can see, the top tabs are way too high.

Tried using SafeAreaView, but now my list items do not show up in the tabs.

[image]

Nothing happens for the height, but its blue and my list elements are missing. Code:

```
//Home top tabs
function HomeTopTabs() {
  return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#2196f3' }}
        forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never', bottom: 'never' }}>
      <TopTab.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeFeed">
        <TopTab.Screen name="HomeFeed" component={Home} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="FriendFeed" component={FriendsScreen} />
      </TopTab.Navigator>
    </SafeAreaView>
    
  );
}
```

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
import { useSafeArea } from "react-native-safe-area-view";
...
const safeArea = useSafeArea()
return(
  <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: safeArea.top}}>
    <HomeTopTabs />
  </View>
)
```

And HomeTopTabs as:

```
function HomeTopTabs() {
  return (
      <TopTab.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeFeed">
        <TopTab.Screen name="HomeFeed" component={Home} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="FriendFeed" component={FriendsScreen} />
      </TopTab.Navigator>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when using this: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Can i see the entire code if possible.
This is happening because you are using the hook inside maybe something like 
renderSomeComponents(){
   //The code
}

Comment: Anytime! No problem :D